# Concatenate 10 uint8 array elements to 5 uint16 array elements

Tags: c, arrays, concatenation

let's suppose I have an array like:

```
uint8 myorigin_array[10] = {0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8,0x9,0xA}
```

I want to concatenate the first element with the second element, the  3rd element with 4th element etc... to have at the end an uint16  array like:

```
uint16 myconcatenated_array[5] = {0X0102,0X0304,0X0506,0X0708,0X90A}
```

What is the fastest way to do this in a loop with concatenating method  (b1 << 8) | b2 ?

Comment: It is actually b1 * 10 + b2 in your example.

Comment: That's not concatenation that's appending digits in base 10

Comment: You cannot get `12` by concatenating two 8-bit bytes of value `1` and `2`. So what do you really want the concatenated value to be? It could be `0x0102` or `0x0201` depending on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0},carr[5],i=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        carr[i]=(arr[(i*2)]*10)+arr[((i*2)+1)];

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%d\n",carr[i]);
}
```

EDIT:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdint.h>

int main()
{
    uint8_t arr[]={0x1,0x2,0x3,0x4,0x5,0x6,0x7,0x8,0x9,0xA};
    int carr[5],i=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        carr[i]=((arr[(i*2)]<<8)|arr[((i*2)+1)]);

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        printf("%#X\n",carr[i]);
}
```

Note: uint8_t can not capable to store

```
       0X0102,0X0304,0X0506,0X0708,0X90A
```

It's range is 0 to 255 (i.e) 0x0 to 0xFF

Comment: thanks! Yes I'm aware about it. Therefore I'm storing them to uint16 values which go to 0xffff